# Getting pids from ps -ef |grep keyword

Tags: linux, shell, daemon

I want to use `ps -ef | grep "keyword"` to determine the pid of a daemon process (there is a unique string in output of ps -ef in it).

I can kill the process with `pkill keyword` is there any command that returns the pid instead of killing it? (pidof or pgrep doesnt work)

Answer (score 295, accepted):

You **can** use `pgrep` as long as you include the `-f` options. That makes `pgrep` match keywords in the whole command (including arguments) instead of just the process name.

```
pgrep -f keyword
```

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep):

> `-f`       The pattern is normally only matched against the process name.  When `-f` is set, the full command line is used.

---

If you really want to avoid pgrep, try:

```
ps -ef | awk '/[k]eyword/{print $2}'
```

Note the `[]` around the first letter of the keyword. That's a useful trick to avoid matching the `awk` command itself.

Comment: ps is overused, and pgrep so underused. Thanks for the post.

Comment: One way to pass the output to kill is:  `kill -9 \`pgrep -f keyword\``

Comment: This answer is the best ever. **So** much time I've wasted with `ps aux | grep chrome`

Comment: Had to use the `[k]` trick on `pgrep -f`. My script was running in a subshell so I think it was picking up its parent command (hard to know for sure - the pid it returned was gone when the command was done executing!)

Comment: @Kris for this use case wouldn't be more straightforward to just use `pkill -9 -f keyword`?

Answer (score 70):

Try

`ps -ef | grep "KEYWORD" | awk '{print $2}'`

That command should give you the PID of the processes with KEYWORD in them. In this instance, `awk` is returning what is in the 2nd column from the output.

Comment: Because this can return more than one pid you can get the first by appending `| head -1`.

Comment: 'head -1' will return grep PID in some linux, Should be tail -1.

Answer (score 28):

`ps -ef | grep KEYWORD | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: Perhaps a typo?  ps -ef | grep KEYWORD | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'

Comment: Do you know how to pass the returned PID into "kill -9" ?!

Comment: @alybadawy just add `| xargs kill -9` to the end

Answer (score 12):

This is available on linux: pidof keyword

Answer (score 11):

I use

```
ps -C "keyword" -o pid=
```

This command should give you a PID number.

Answer (score 10):

To kill a process by a specific keyword you could create an alias in `~/.bashrc` (linux) or `~/.bash_profile` (mac).

```
alias killps="kill -9 `ps -ef | grep '[k]eyword' | awk '{print $2}'`"
```

Comment: Perfect! Adding a pipe to the end of `| head -1` wraps this all up nice and neat.