# I want to force my app to close other background application before startup

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, atom-editor

I want to force other app to quit before launching my application like prompting to close. It seems to me a dead end. I can block keys but not other app running in taskbar

Comment: Which OS is your app running on?

Comment: i am using linux x64

Answer (score 0):

You can use shelljs and execute a shell command to get the process ID of the application that you want to close. e.g. see [this answer of how to get pid using pgrep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120304/getting-pids-from-ps-ef-grep-keyword)

Once you have the PID you can kill that process using process.kill(PID)

This is the first thing you can do inside your app.on('ready', eventHandler) ;

Comment: You are not getting my problem, i want to stop user to close every window before my app launch since i don't know the current open application how would i close it in the first place.
My Task- To stop user from capturing my app activity example- Online Examination prompt you to not close application else test will be closed. I am using nodejs javascipt in electron framework so i have tried kiosk mode but failed(only full window working) since user can swap windows and minimize then i used javascript to block some key combination but  still there is minimize window button visible